# Do networking storage protocols like NFS and SMB have protection of data against corruption during wire transmition?

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

According to what I read briefly about NFS today - it has no such protection. I mean something like CRC for blocks,packets and so on.
And I wonder - what is the possibility of data corruption when NFS is used as storage solution in production environment with enterprise network and server equipment? Is this possibility much higher when using home-level equipment?

Comment: It is often the case that high level protocols like this are implemented on top of something more rudimentary like TCP. In the case of NFS and SMB, they use TCP and therefore they benefit from the data integrity [guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission) that are implemented in the TCP protocol itself. -- This isn't really a complete answer so I have left it as a comment for now.

Comment: What @Romen says is the same assumption built into every program in every system: that the systems underneath implement enough protection and checking to ensure data integrity. The hard disk itself implements CRC at the sector level and wire transmission protocols tend to use error checking by their nature so in theory programs can assume that whatever data appear is correct. Until it provably isn't such as where a program implements compression where later data is dependent on earlier data being correct.

Answer (score 0):

Disk failure is more likely for low-price low-quality hardware, without saying.

You should mostly pay attention to the difference between hard/soft mounts in NFS.
Soft will time out on error, but hard will block until it succeeds.

Soft mount then may lose data with a sequence like that:

```
Write 1: succeeds
Write 2: succeeds
NFS server crashes
Write 3: fails, due to time out
Write 4: fails, due to time out
NFS server recovers (very quickly)
Write 5: succeeds
Write 6: succeeds
```

The result will be lost data with missing data (holes) in your file.